# Check if all values in a row across certain columns are equal while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("l", "m", "n", "o"),
                 c2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a"),
                 c3 = c("b", NA, "a", "b"),
                 c4 = c("a", "a", "a", "NA"))
> print(df)
  c1 c2   c3 c4
1  l  a    b  a
2  m  a <NA>  a
3  n  a    a  a
4  o  a    b NA
```

I would like to check if, for each row, the values from columns `c2`, `c3`, and `c4` are equal, but ignoring NA values. That is, the desired result is a new column that is `FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE`. I'd like to do this using `dplyr` functions if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another `dplyr` approach that does not use `rowwise`. `rowwise` is very readable but terribly inefficient for even moderately sized data sets:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(eq = apply(pick(c2:c4), 1, n_distinct, na.rm = T) == 1)
#   c1 c2   c3 c4    eq
# 1  l  a    b  a FALSE
# 2  m  a <NA>  a  TRUE
# 3  n  a    a  a  TRUE
# 4  o  a    b NA FALSE
```

This uses base R function `apply`. If you had `purrr` loaded then this could easily be implement `pmap_lgl`.

**Benchmark**

Comparing the `dplyr` answers:

```r
set.seed(1)
idx <- sample(1:nrow(df), 1E4, replace = T)
dat <- df[idx, ]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  without_rowwise = dat |>
    mutate(eq = apply(pick(c2:c4), 1, n_distinct, na.rm = T) == 1),
  rowwise = dat %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(check = c_across(c2:c4) %>% na.omit() %>% n_distinct() == 1) %>%
    ungroup(),
  times = 20L
)

Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 without_rowwise  159.0973  166.6416  168.4436  168.7185  170.5299  179.0234    20  a 
         rowwise 7838.2970 7913.8968 8044.4391 7996.7697 8103.2887 8555.1685    20   b
```

Comment: What library is `pick` from?

Comment: @BenS. it's from dplyr

Comment: Great use of `dplyr::pick`. +1

Comment: I guess I need to update my dplyr!

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this one as it's what I ended up using, the rowwise approach's slowness got to me

Comment: @BenS. `pick` was added in dplyr 1.1.0. Before that, people would use `across` without a function argument, but this is not recommended and why they introduced this new verb.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(check = c_across(c2:c4) %>% n_distinct(na.rm = TRUE) == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This uses

- `rowwise` to do the check per row
- `c_across` to use tidyselect to select columns
- `n_distinct` to find the number of unique values
- and `==` to compare to 1.

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 × 5
> # Rowwise: 
>   c1    c2    c3    c4    check
>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
> 1 l     a     b     a     FALSE
> 2 m     a     NA    a     TRUE 
> 3 n     a     a     a     TRUE 
> 4 o     a     b     NA    FALSE
> ```

I think this answer is very readable, but it is also really slow once you have thousands of rows. In that case, you may want to consider other answers here.

Comment: `n_distinct` has `na.rm`.  This works: ```df %>% mutate(check = n_distinct(c_across(c2:c4), na.rm = T) == 1, .by = c1)```. `rowwise()` is the safer approach since we are not sure if `c1` is a unique identifier.

Comment: @M-- Nice. And `.by` is still listed as experimental, so I avoid it for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can first define the columns of interest(`ccols`) then use `apply` to check if all the values in the rows are the same as those in the first (`index = 1`), excluding those with `NA` (via `!is.na(x)`)

```
ccols <- c("c2", "c3", "c4")
apply(df[ccols], index = 1, 
      function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] == x[!is.na(x)][1]))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you wanted to create an indicator variable instead of just a vector:

```
df$allequal <- apply(df[ccols], 1, 
                     function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] == x[!is.na(x)][1]))

#  c1 c2   c3 c4 allequal
#1  l  a    b  a    FALSE
#2  m  a <NA>  a     TRUE
#3  n  a    a  a     TRUE
#4  o  a    b NA    FALSE
```

Of add a `+` right before `any()` to make the indicator variable 1/0 instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE`:

```
df$allequal <- apply(df[ccols], 1, 
                     function(x) +all(x[!is.na(x)] == x[!is.na(x)][1]))

#  c1 c2   c3 c4 allequal
#1  l  a    b  a        0
#2  m  a <NA>  a        1
#3  n  a    a  a        1
#4  o  a    b NA        0
```

(Although this isn't a tidyverse approach, a base R approach may be useful to some.)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in a vectorised fashion without looping over rows. E.g.:

```
Reduce(`&`, lapply(Map(`==`, df["c2"], df[c("c3","c4")]), \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), TRUE)))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Which should be waaay more efficient on large data:

```
df <- df[rep(1:4,1e6),]

system.time({
    Reduce(`&`, lapply(Map(`==`, df["c2"], df[c("c3","c4")]), \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), TRUE)))
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.05    0.01    0.06 


system.time({
    ccols <- c("c2", "c3", "c4")
    apply(df[ccols], 1, function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] == x[!is.na(x)][1]))
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  16.43    0.04   16.45
```

Comment: Thanks, for my use case I am interested in the most readable way but certainly for some use cases speed is more important.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `purrr`s `pmap_vec`:

With `pmap_vec` we apply a function (in this case an anonymous function) to each element of a list (in this case row of the data frame). These elements are passed as separate arguments to the function we use. Inside this function, `...` captures these separate arguments and we check with `== .x` if all are equal to the placeholder `.x` of the first value from c1 (in this case `a`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  select(-c1) %>% 
  pmap_vec(~ all(na.omit(c(...)) == .x))
```

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```